# How to clone and resize a dual-boot SSD from a smaller to a bigger SSD disk?

Tags: dual-boot, ssd, clone

So, I have this Windows 7/Ubuntu 16.04 dual boot system, tightly fitted on a 120GB SSD. I would like to migrate it to a bigger ~500GB SSD and resize the partitions in order to have more space. The big SSD is currently installed in my desktop. The /home partition of Ubuntu is encrypted. So, I would like to make the Windows 7 NTFS partition about 200GB, 200GB for /home and about 60GB for the ubuntu root. I'm hoping that you would be able to give me some directions on how to proceed. I'm attaching a screenshot of GParted:

[image]

Comment: Do you really want Windows 7, it is EoL - End of Life. Also Ubuntu 20.04 will be out shortly and now then may be a good time to install either 18.04LTS or 20.04LTS. With Ubuntu often easier to do a new clean install & restore from your backups. And then you still have old drive to get anything your backup forgot, so you then confirm your backup process is good. Old installs are BIOS. Is system UEFI as all systems since 2012 are UEFI.

Comment: I see what you mean. However, I kinda don't have the time to do a full reinstall and configure all the things I need for work. Ubuntu is my primary workhorse. It still has a year until EOL, and it just works. Furthermore, 16.04 was the last version that supports encryption of the home folder as part of the standard upgrade. Windows is for fun and games. No sensitive information goes there. There are still hacks to keep it updated too.

Comment: A backup is to restore system when (not if) hard drive fails. And if you have an SSD, you can install Ubuntu in approx. 10 Min. Then copy /home into new install from backup and that should be most of your configuration. Only if you edited system may some settings in /etc need to be updated. (I edit grub settings, but copy into /home so backup includes that). And export list of installed apps. Reinstalling those may take longer than install, but less than an hour unless really slow Internet.

Comment: Your approach may be faster and smarter. However, I'm sure that there will be users with up-to-date operating systems, with similar disk partitioning on a small disk, that will find the reply to the original question useful. So, let us don't change the point.

Comment: I have seen some suggest this which is a backup tool but allows copy to new drive. http://clonezilla.org. If image copy, you cannot have old & new drives connected at same time as duplicate UUIDs are not allowed. You can change one or the other's UUIDs. But have to edit fstab, & reinstall grub. Some just use dd whose nickname is "DATA DESTROYER" as any typo erases permanently all data on wrong drive and is slow as it copies blank space also, but is a byte for byte copy. Then resize with gparted.